# MUI Lab Not Exporting AdapterDateFns

Tags: material-ui

```
/** @license MUI v5.0.0-alpha.63
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
/* eslint-disable import/export */
export { default as Alert } from './Alert';
export * from './Alert';
export { default as AlertTitle } from './AlertTitle';
export * from './AlertTitle';
export { default as Autocomplete } from './Autocomplete';
export * from './Autocomplete';
export { default as AvatarGroup } from './AvatarGroup';
export * from './AvatarGroup';
export { default as CalendarPicker } from './CalendarPicker';
export * from './CalendarPicker';
export { default as ClockPicker } from './ClockPicker';
export * from './ClockPicker';
export { default as DatePicker } from './DatePicker';
export * from './DatePicker';
export { default as DateRangePicker } from './DateRangePicker';
export * from './DateRangePicker';
...
```

It is simply not being exported from index.js at node_modules > @mui >lab > index.js
The directory is there with export `{ default } from '@date-io/date-fns';` in index.js

I'm running versions `"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.63",` and `"@mui/material": "^5.0.0-alpha.24",`

Comment: See this [migration guide](https://mui.com/guides/pickers-migration/#imports) for V5

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the export here:

```
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/modern/AdapterDateFns";
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed `date-fns` and it resolved the issue for me:

```
npm i date-fns
```